# What is the use of Encumbrances in Corda

Tags: corda

In Corda I was able to spend my encumbering state in a stand alone transaction without the encumbered state. Is this by design or am I missing something?

As of now I am able to enforce encumbrances only through my contract.

I have implemented encumbrance using

```
 transactionBuilder.addOutputState(state =  TesterState(data = 1, participants = listOf(serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first())),contract =  TesterContract.ID, notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first(), encumbrance = 1)
    transactionBuilder.addOutputState(state =TimeEncumbranceState(Timestamp =  System.currentTimeMillis(), participants =  listOf(serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first())),contract =  TimeEncumbranceContract.ID,notary =  serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first())
```

I am also able to consume these states individually if the contract checks for encumbrance are absent.

Are there any non-contract enforcement of encumbrance?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have `State A` (the encumbered state) to be encumbered by `State B` (the encumbrance/encumbering state). The encumbrance state, if present, forces additional controls over the encumbered state. You cannot spend `encumbered state` without the `encumbrance state`

However, in the current encumbrance design as of `Corda v3.x`, nobody stops you from spending `encumbrance state` on its own (so a malicious user could indeed freeze A because A refers to B by `stateRef`)

You can easily fix the aforementioned issue by always requiring circular encumbrance links. State A encumbered by State B, State B encumbered by State A. `A->B->A` therefore B cannot be spent on its own.

Corda 4.x should have added bidirectional checks against encumbrances. See [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/4089) However, encumbrances are not encouraged to be used yet.